# Is there a charater limit in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to insert a query with 1,397,025 characters and doesn't get it inserted. The server doesn't provide me with an error message. So my thought was, is there a character limit for a query?

Comment: `insert a query`: are you trying to execute an insert statement with a value having ~ 1.4 MB of data?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the datatype that you are using, but from your question it seems its TEXT.

Quote from [Mysql Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html)

> A TEXT column with a maximum length of 65,535 (216 − 1) characters.
>   The effective maximum length is less if the value contains multibyte
>   characters. Each TEXT value is stored using a 2-byte length prefix
>   that indicates the number of bytes in the value.
>
> An optional length M can be given for this type. If this is done,
>   MySQL creates the column as the smallest TEXT type large enough to
>   hold values M characters long.

If you are talking about buffer size,

> Most of these program variables also can be set at server startup by
>   using the same syntax that applies to specifying program options. For
>   example, mysql has a max_allowed_packet variable that controls the
>   maximum size of its communication buffer. To set the
>   max_allowed_packet variable for mysql to a value of 16MB, use either
>   of the following commands:
>
> shell> mysql --max_allowed_packet=16777216 shell> mysql
>   --max_allowed_packet=16M The first command specifies the value in bytes. The second specifies the value in megabytes. For variables that
>   take a numeric value, the value can be given with a suffix of K, M, or
>   G (either uppercase or lowercase) to indicate a multiplier of 1024,
>   10242 or 10243. (For example, when used to set max_allowed_packet, the
>   suffixes indicate units of kilobytes, megabytes, or gigabytes.)

If you are using the mysql client program, its default max_allowed_packet variable is 16MB. To set a larger value, start mysql like this:

shell> mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M
That sets the packet size to 32MB.

The server's default max_allowed_packet value is 1MB. You can increase this if the server needs to handle big queries (for example, if you are working with big BLOB columns). For example, to set the variable to 16MB, start the server like this:

shell> mysqld --max_allowed_packet=16M

Refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html